# What's the name for a 3d U shape?

Tags: geometry

Imagine a tube, split in half laterally, discarding one of the halves. Does the remaining shape have a name?  [image: Like this].

Comment: Like a half pipe?
I'd just say half pipe.

Comment: I'd call it a disk.

Comment: It can be called a circular trough.

Comment: @Couchy311 >implying we allow equivalence under ambient isotopy.

Then the homotopy theorist comes and calls it a point smh.

Comment: Are you referring to something like [this](https://i.imgur.com/HPftCXx.png)? I'd like to know as well.

Comment: @ExtremeRaider That's looks like the tip of an elliptic paraboloid.

Comment: @JackozeeHakkiuz so it's not the same shape that the OP is referring to?

Comment: The description sounds like a semicircular cylinder to me.
@Pink Sweetener could you post a picture?

Comment: @ExtremeRaider No closer to [this](https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/z/gold-3d-letter-u-3848556.jpg), except the curve is half of a circle.

Comment: I think @JackozeeHakkiuz is the closest so far with "halfpipe".  Of course, a real world halfpipe is inside of a [box](https://s3.amazonaws.com/gs-waymarking-images/5525a336-6fef-45a3-911e-582025388ab1_d.jpg), where as the shape I describe is round on the outside.  I've added a new picture to the question.

Comment: Is the cross section a circle or a square?

Comment: Does it look like this picture https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/531608/how-to-find-the-center-of-mass-of-half-a-torus

Comment: @QthePlatypus nope, it's got corners, like in the image above.

Comment: Nobody has proposed to name it plainly "letter C".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't have a formal name for it but circle with a smaller circle cut out of it is an "annulus".  Extruding a shape into 3d with a rectangle makes it a prism so the full shape would be "annula-prism" and a half version of the shape would be a "semi-annula-prism".

If the tube is round rather then rectangular (so it looks like a donut) it is a half-torus.